# Mustache section values are overridden

Tags: templates, mustache, overriding

How to get this output:

```
<h1>Colors</h1>
<li><strong>red</strong></li>
<li><a href="#Green">green</a></li>
<li><a href="#Blue">blue</a></li>
```

From this template:

```
<h1>{{header}}</h1>
{{#bug}}
{{/bug}}

{{#items}}
  {{#first}}
    <li><strong>{{name}}</strong></li>
  {{/first}}
  {{#link}}
    <li><a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/link}}
{{/items}}

{{#empty}}
  <p>The list is empty.</p>
{{/empty}}
```

This data:

```
{
  "header": "Colors",
  "first": true,
  "items": [
      {"name": "red", "first": true, "url": "#Red"},
      {"name": "green", "link": true, "url": "#Green"},
      {"name": "blue", "link": true, "url": "#Blue"}
  ],
  "empty": false
}
```

So that the first field is not overridden.

Currently I get this output:

```
<h1>Colors</h1>
<li><strong>red</strong></li>
<li><strong>green</strong></li>
<li><a href="#Green">green</a></li>
<li><strong>blue</strong></li>
<li><a href="#Blue">blue</a></li>
```

I'm testing [here](https://mustache.github.io/#demo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `first` key is defined at two levels: at the item level, and at the root level.

When it is not defined at the item level, the Mustache engines digs in, and uses the one defined at the root level. This is called the Mustache context stack, and you have just learnt it the hard way.

Now the answer is simple, insn't it? In order to prevent the Mustache engine to dig in the context stack and look for `first` at the root level, make sure `first` is defined at the item level, for **all** items. Set it to `false` for all items but the first.